# Why is recommended to add extra files in a python source package?

Tags: python, package, packaging

There are python tools like [check-manifest](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/check-manifest), to verify that all your files under your vcs are included also in your `MANIFEST.in`. And releasing helpers like [zest.releaser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zest.releaser) recommend you to use them.

I think files in `tests` or `docs` directories are never used directly from the python package. Usually services like [read the docs](https://readthedocs.org/) or [travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/) are going to access that files, and they get the files from the vcs, not from the package. I have seen also packages including `.travis.yml` files, what makes even less sense to me.

What is the advantage of including all the files in the python package?

Comment: Note that excluding `.travis.yml` is given as a specific example in the `check-manifest` docs. On the other hand, why bother; what's the *disadvantage* of including them that makes the extra effort to exclude them worth it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe A disadvantage is that, by default, a minimal set of files are included in the package ([python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/sourcedist.html#specifying-the-files-to-distribute)). You need to create and maintain the `MANIFEST.in` file, keeping it manually in sync with your vcs. Other disadvantage is that the package size is bigger, maybe just a few kbs, but why do it bigger if we don't gain anything? I see more effort including the files, but that's not the point of my question, what I want to know what I gain including the files.